# meaning of the phrase "some kind of X"

Tags: phrase-meaning

I found a sentence on Google.

> He is some kind of artist,I believe.

In this sentence,I am so confused with the phrase
"some kind of".

> Does it mean,
>   **an artist he did not know** or **a good artist**?

Comment: You should know that referring to someone as ***some** kind of X* is particularly common in negative / condemnatory / dismissive contexts, especially when coupled with *I think* or *I believe*. There's often an implication of *I don't think very highly of X's in general, so I neither know nor care which **particular** type of X he is.*

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker, I would interpret that as "He is [a type] of artist, I believe."  For example, he might be someone who sketches, or a painter, or a sculptor.

Depending on context, I might interpret it as "He is [an amateur] artist, I believe."

Either way, I would take it to mean that the speaker wasn't 100% sure, but believed that to be true.

Answer (score 1):

I think the expression is generally used meaning sui generis, of its own kind:

***[Kind of/sort of](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kind+of)***:

> - In conversation and in less formal writing, people use sort of or kind of in front of a noun ***to say that something could be described as being a particular thing***.
>
>   - It's a sort of dictionary of dictionaries.
>   - I'm a kind of anarchist, I suppose.

Collins Dictionary